# Not able to upload Images on to Google Firebase Storage using iOS Swift API

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, image-uploading, firebase-storage

Earlier i was able to upload Images onto Google Firebase Strage. but suddenly it's not working.

Below is the code:

```
private func uploadEmergencyImages(images: [Int: URL], emergencyId: String){
    let imagesRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("incidents").child(emergencyId).child("images")

    if(!images.isEmpty){
        for (key, value) in images {
            print("Image to be Uploaded = \(value.absoluteString)")

            let imageData = try! Data(contentsOf: value)
            //                let image = UIImage(data: imageData)

            let metaData = StorageMetadata()
            metaData.contentType = "image/png"
            imagesRef.child("Image_\(key+1).png").putData(imageData, metadata: metaData) { (storageMetaData, storageError) in
                if(storageError != nil){
                    print("Error - While uploading Image:: \(storageError.debugDescription)")
                }else{
                    print("Upload completed...")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the Error message (NOTE: Here i have masked my firebasePrjName with 'XXX' for this post.)

> 2018-08-23 20:25:54.758092+0300 XXX[44855:1058133] [AXRun-PID] Client
>   requesting unsuspension of PID:44870 Name: 2018-08-23
>   20:25:55.833590+0300 XXX[44855:1057851] [AXRun-PID] Client requesting
>   unsuspension of PID:44870 Name: 2018-08-23
>   20:25:57.512286+0300 XXX[44855:1057987] [discovery] errors encountered
>   while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query
>   cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled} New
>   Incident Key = -LKboaL9nTohkCHuYp1U Image to be Uploaded =
>   file:///Users/macbookpro/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/863EEA6A-F1F5-4A6C-B19B-D686D81486F4/data/Containers/Data/Application/F0D6F426-EE5E-4B45-8D1F-3B880C049DF3/tmp/39F05E90-3F8F-4A40-84CB-1931D1E9C7CA.jpeg
>   2018-08-23 20:26:07.359567+0300 XXX[44855:1058132] TIC TCP Conn Failed
>   [4:0x60400036ffc0]: 3:-9802 Err(-9802) 2018-08-23 20:26:07.360138+0300
>   XXX[44855:1058132] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed
>   (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802) 2018-08-23 20:26:07.360235+0300
>   XXX[44855:1058132] Task .<1>
>   HTTP load failed (error code: -1200 [3:-9802]) 2018-08-23
>   20:26:07.360437+0300 XXX[44855:1057735] Task
>   .<1> finished with error - code:
>   -1200 Error - While uploading Image:: Optional(Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13000 "An unknown error occurred,
>   please check the server response."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to
>   the server anyway?, NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred,
>   please check the server response., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3,
>   NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=(
>       "",
>       "" ), NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/XXX-ots.appspot.com/o/incidents%2F-LKboaL9nTohkCHuYp1U%2Fimages%2FImage_1.png?uploadType=resumable&name=incidents%2F-LKboaL9nTohkCHuYp1U%2Fimages%2FImage_1.png,
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/XXX-ots.appspot.com/o/incidents%2F-LKboaL9nTohkCHuYp1U%2Fimages%2FImage_1.png?uploadType=resumable&name=incidents%2F-LKboaL9nTohkCHuYp1U%2Fimages%2FImage_1.png,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x600000647290 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork
>   Code=-1200 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0,
>   kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=,
>   _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9802, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=(
>       "",
>       "" )}}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802,
>   object=incidents/-LKboaL9nTohkCHuYp1U/images/Image_1.png,
>   ResponseErrorDomain=NSURLErrorDomain, bucket=XXX-ots.appspot.com,
>   NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=,
>   ResponseErrorCode=-1200})

I had tried to modify my `info.plist` file as below also, but it did not work:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Any lead is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me **(swift 4 Code)**

```
let storageRef = DBProvider.Instance.imageStorageRef.child(user!.uid) // Put Here your Storage Referance  
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(youimagehere, 1.0) // put your image Here

storageRef.putData(imageData!, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

    if error == nil
    {
        let path = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
        print(path)
    }
})
```

Make sure you have enabled firebase storage **read, write** Permission from your Firebase project.

[image]

Comment: Hi Thanks for you response. But still not working for me. i have even tried another way.                                                                                                                       
    ` imagesRef.child("Image_\(key+1).png").putFile(from: value, metadata: nil)`                                                                I had even created separate Firebase Project. But no hope.

Comment: @RavindraSingh Then make sure you have enabled firebase storage Upload Permission from your Firebase project.

Comment: @RavindraSingh I Check it and it's final you have an issue with a read-write permission issue in firebase storage because your error log URL getting that error. **Check this is your Error Log URL**   https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/XXX-ots.appspot.com/o/incidents%2F-LKboaL9nTohkCHuYp1U%2Fimages%2FImage_1.png?uploadType=resumable&name=incidents%2F-LKboaL9nTohkCHuYp1U%2Fimages%2FImage_1.png

Comment: @RavindraSingh Check my Edited Answer.

Comment: I have set my rule as ::                            service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
} .        Is there any other place where i have to set rule.        If you can guide me how to "enabled firebase storage Upload Permission ", would be great help.     NOTE: FYI, I am not facing any issue to enter information into "Firebase Database".       i have set rule as public read & write. if you want i can share "GoogleService-Info.plist" file of my trial prj. so that you can also reproduce this error.